# Splitting polyline feature in ArcGIS Desktop causes part of feature above split point to disappear?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, splitting

Why is it, when I split a polyline feature in ArcGIS Desktop, that the part of the feature above the split point disappears?

Video of it happening: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQyNn.jpg

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to contain useful information, like the version of the software in use, and the coordinate system(s) of the data involved, and the data format, and the spatial reference(s) defined in the environment and feature classes (especially the XY tolerance and XY resolution)

Comment: Do you have a definition query on the layer that may be showing features of a certain length? Splitting the line may change the length of the features and then hides them. Apart from that, it may have something to do with the fact that it's multi-part geometry as was indicated by ahmadhanb's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think the line is multipart line feature. To solve the problem, you need to explode the line by selecting the line and click on [Explode Multipart Feature](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/separating-a-multipart-feature.htm) [image] exists on advance editing toolbar. After that you can use split tool if needed.